# How to fix this complex layout?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried with bootstrap but couldn't fix this:

http://clubcanindelestrie.com/images/layouts.png

I suppose that flexbox could do the job but can't figure it out. Help please!

Comment: Although you can do this with Flexbox, you would need at least 2 containers and toggling visibility on them; I think CSS Grid is a better option for this kind of layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this layout using *either* Flexbox or CSS Grid, IMO, Grid would be better, since you only have to manage one container with its items, instead of two separate flex-items with their content as well.

Also with Grid you can change the position of all the items inside fairly easy. Take a look at both examples below.

**Flexbox**

```css
.flex,
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
}

.flex .wrap {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.item {
  min-height: 100px;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.wrapper1 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper1 .flex-item-2 {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper2 .flex-item-2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flex-item-3 {
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item-3 p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Just coloring */

.flex-item-1 {
  background-color: red
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background-color: skyblue
}

.flex-item-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 590px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .wrapper1 .flex-item-2 {
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper2 .flex-item-2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrap wrapper1">
    <div class="item flex-item-1">1</div>
    <div class="item flex-item-2">2</div>
    <div class="item flex-item-3">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap wrapper2">
    <div class="item flex-item-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Grid**

With CSS Grid you have a single container with its items, which you can arrange in a lot of different ways, positioning elements in any way you need as well as making each element use the space you need. (Consider reading [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/))

The most important rules you need to look at in the following example are:

`display: grid;`: We define which will be de Grid container.

`grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);`: We define how many rows we want to have in the grid, this can be customized in many ways, but in the example we use the `repeat()` function to define 2 rows, each with a height of `100px`.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`: Same as the rows, we define that we need 2 columns, and each column will use *1 fraction of the available space*; with this we have each *column* using basically 50% of the screen.

`grid-template-areas: "item1 item2" "item3 item2";`: With template-areas, we can build something like a visual representation of how our grid should look. Each group string (`""`) represents one row, you specify a name for a item that should occupy that column space, so `"item1 item2"` tells the grid that in one row, the first column should be used by the element with the `item1` `grid-area`, and the second column by the element with the `item2` name;

One you have this, you only need to define which item is `item1` and which `item2` (or item3, or 4, 5....etc). The other way to do this is using the property `grid-column` or `grid-row` to define from which to which *grid-line* an element should render, outputting the same end result.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "item1 item2" "item3 item2";
}

.grid-item-1 {
  grid-area: item1;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-area: item2;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  grid-area: item3;
  background-color: yellow;
  /*You can also mix both approaches*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.grid-item-3 p{
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 590px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "item1" "item2" "item3";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item grid-item-3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code you provided in the comments section with fixes made:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problems arise when I put some text in the boxes: with flexbox, the width of the column vary with the content, it should be fixed at 50% each and I want to align the content of box 3 to the bottom (flex-end).

Comment: @SergioB I made the changes, you just have to specify the `flex` property to have a value of `1 0 50%`... Also what do you mean with the box 3 alignment? How do you expect that to look?

Comment: Alright; Check the flexbox example again; I did it using position absolute and relative on the `p` and `.flex-item-3` elements respectively; you could also do this by making `.flex-item-3` a flex-container as well and orienting it to `column`... I'd just like you to notice that this keeps increasing CSS size, while doing it with Grid would require a lot less code

Comment: I gave the CSS grid a try and it seems a lot easier:
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .grid-container > div {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .item2 {
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    }

    .item3{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
but the item2 block is on the left side instead of being on the right side. How would you fix this?

Comment: I already gave you a working example for CSS Grid, any reason to rebuild it from scratch? Take a look at the example I built, I'll edit the answer to kinda explain what each rule does

Comment: @SergioB I added an explanation for the CSS Grid code just before the second snippet, take a look and let me know if it helped you... also, in the code you provided, to fix the issue you can replace `.item2 { grid-row: 1 / span 2; }` with just `.item2{grid-column: span 2}`

Comment: There is a problem with the code you gave me: the boxes don't stretch and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the boxes don't stretch*"? when do you see this happening?